# Numerical array too long in c++ : how can I circumvent this?

Tags: c++, arrays

DISCLAIMER: I am at a *very* entry level in c++ (or any language)... I searched for similar questions but found none

I am trying to write a simple program which should make some operations on an array as big as `int pop[100000000][4]` (10^8); however my compiler crashs even for a `int pop[130000][4]` array... is there any way out? Am I using a wrong approach?

(For now I am limiting myself to a very simple program, my aim is to generate random numbers in the array[][0] every "turn" to simulate a population and work with that).

Thanks for your time and attention

Comment: You are trying to allocate static storage. You cannot allocate this much on the stack. Use dynamic allocation, via "new", auto pop = new int[13000*4]

Comment: your compiler crashes?

Comment: @RyanHaining, you left out the smiley :)

Comment: @Puppy's pissing at each corner they can find, and even on your living rooms floor. That's why I like cats, they're so neat.

Comment: @RyanHaining, yeah, sorry, edited, it was a shorthand, in the actual program I wrote 100000000

Comment: Sorry if I am new, but what did I do wrong to get a -3 score? I looked for similar questions but found none, did I overlook something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of 130000 * 4 ints is going to be huge, and likely not something you want stored locally (in reality, on the stack where it generally won't fit).

Instead you can use dynamic allocation to get heap storage,  the recommended means would be a `vector` of `vector`s

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> pop(130000, std::vector<int>(4));
pop[12000][1] = 9; // expected syntax
```

`vector`s are dynamic, so know that they can be changed with [all sorts of calls](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

If you're a new programmer and trying to write a simple programmer, you should consider *not* using 203KiB of ints

Comment: Thanks! You see, I am studying Physics so I had just a simple course on C++, and I am trying to make a numerical simulation... I probably need those 10^8 "units"...

Comment: Oh, I see what silly me did... if int are at least 16 bit (2 byte) long, I am asking for at least 2*4*10^8 byte ≈ 1 GB of an array.... Non computer guys like me usually treat the machine like a magical cube....

Comment: @Barat in the context of most programming language `^` is a bitwise XOR, not an exponential operator.  Some languages (python comes to mind) use `**` for exponentiation, in C++ you can use the function `std::pow`

Comment: also `int` is usually 4 bytes

Comment: I know of the ^ bit, sorry for having used a misleading format, I was thinking "as a physicist"